# create a mask given bounding box

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
arr = []
j =0 
for img in train['image_id'].unique():
    bbox = train[train['image_id'] == img]   #bbox[0] = x ,similarly others 
    template = np.zeros((1024,1024))
    j+=1
    for i in train.itertuples():
        template[i._6:i._6 + i._8  ,  i._7:i._7 + i._9] = 1 
    arr.append(template)
```

here i._6 , i._8 , i._7 , i._9
are values of bounding boxes
Is there a way to make this code fast

Comment: Can you please provide a closed example that can be worked with (i.e. a copy-paste example)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using numpy, you can use [`numba`'s JIT compiler](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html) to trivially get some speed enhancements.

```py
from numba import jit

@jit
def myfunction()..
```

This will [compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) your code and cache it, so the first call may be faster, and subsequent calls to the function can be *extremely* fast.

However, you should also investigate what is actually slowing in your code and try to improve it.

This is known as [profiling, and can be done with the standard libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) via `cProfile` (more specialized 3rd-party packages exist too)

[SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) is a simple viewer for the output files from `cProfile`

```sh
python -m cProfile -o program.profile my_program.py
snakeviz program.profile
```

You are likely to see speed improvements replacing Python constructs (such as `tuples` and `for` loops) with `numpy` equivalents wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used opencv to get a similar effect

```
for img in train['image_id'].unique():
    bbox = train[train['image_id'] == img]
    template = np.zeros((1024,1024))
    for i in bbox.itertuples():
        cv2.rectangle(template , (i._6 , i._7) , (i._6 + i._8  , i._7 + i._9)  , (255,255,255) ,-1)
    
    cv2.imwrite('masked/'+img+'.jpg',template)
```